# How to remove "New Application"

Tags: 20.04, uninstall

There are two "New Application" icons in my list of installed software but clicking either of them leads nowhere except to display the (error) message

```
    Failed to launch "New Application"
    Desktop file didn't specify Exec field
```

Right-clicking on the icons and selecting Show Details shows message

```
    Sorry!  There are no details for that application.
```

EDIT : I have looked at almost all of the entries under /usr/share/applications (missing only a few that I recognized as valid) and did not find any with Name "New Application", or with a blank Exec field.

I have no idea what programs these might have been.  Obviously they failed to install properly, and I wonder how to find them and properly uninstall them, whatever they are.   Is there some way to do that??

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `.desktop` configuration files under `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications`.

Look at the contents these files to see if there are any bad entries.  Specifically, look for "New Application" and whether or not the `exec` field is blank, since those are the specific errors you are getting.

To speed up the search, you can try to pick out the ones that aren't immediately recognizable as other applications.

Comment: Thank you, Richard and Nmath.  The offending files (Name "New Application" and missing Exec specification) were both located in ~/.local/share/applications.  I deleted both files and the two "mystery" icons are now gone.  Thanks again!